# Como fazer reaproveitamento de código em dois projeto similares

Tags: android

Conclui um projeto e preciso fazer outro com o mesmo contexto. O problema é que sei que vou encontrar bugs e irei evoluir o código quando estiver desenvolvendo o segundo. Como eu faço de um jeito de que consiga corrigir um bug nos dois projetos ao mesmo tempo sem ter que abrir um por um e sem que tenha que perder as particularidades que cada um tem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure o seu `Build Path` para usar códigos fontes que não estão dentro do seu projeto.

Clique em `Link Source...` e indique o caminho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça isso nos seus dois projetos, dessa forma você terá uma base única, toda vez que você mudar o código fonte para um estará mudando o código fonte do outro também. Mas você terá que se certificar que a interface de cada um está acompanhando as melhoria do seu código base.

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas se eu tiver o seguinte problema: Tenho uma Lista de Noticia nos dois projetos, porém um precisa de somente 1 imagem para cada item da listview, o outro precisa de dois.

Comment: @Othon não entendi muito bem seu exemplo, mas é importante você separar sua interface (parte gráfica) da lógica principal do seu programa. Assim você pode tratar as peculiaridades de cada projeto na classe que trata a parte gráfica.

Comment: Então eu pegaria a model e criaria uma biblioteca dela?

Comment: @Othon O que é a model? Não precisa criar uma biblioteca, o que eu recomendo é pegar as classes (.java) que são base e colocar em separado dos dois projetos, daí em ambos projetos você adiciona as classes bases no seu _build path_. Na pasta `src` de cada projeto você terá apenas as classes que são específicas daquele projeto, como por exemplo a classe das activity's.

Comment: Ok. Model View Control sao as camadas que compõe o padrão MVC. É dele que surge a ideia da separação da lógica(model) da visual(view). A control é responsável pela comunicação entre as duas camadas bem como algum tipo de verficação da informação passada(como por exemplo uma data de forma errada). A sua resposta me deu uma luz sobre o que fazer

Answer (score 1):

basta pegar aquilo que é comum para os dois e transformar em uma biblioteca, e ai usar a referencia nos dois

Comment: Boa Tarde Paulo,

Comment: Estávamos pensando nisso, porém já temos um projeto completo e daria muito trabalho tentar tirar a parte incomum. Nao teria outro jeito? É muito dificil identificar o que eu posso reaproveitar em outros projetos

Comment: De forma elegante e que eu conheça não.